# How can I locally preview a Markdown Wiki?

Tags: markdown, bitbucket

Bitbucket's Wiki uses Markdown syntax.

There are plenty of ways to preview a single `.md` file, but is there a way to preview a whole markdown site under **OS X**? I.e. something that will handle **multiple files at once, with internal links working**.

Searching for it only yields dozens of solutions for single files, but none *apparently* is supposed to work for this setup.

Comment: For those that came here wanting any way of viewing BitBucket markdown in advance (and not specifically an efficient local method) then there is this little page, which purports to display a BitBucket markdown *theme*, which presumably approximates to styling, but doesn't support tables as BitBucket does, which may mean there are some other syntax differences, but none-the-less does more-or-less work: http://www.writeme.mattstow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many markdown editors have sprung into existence since this question was posted, that allow to browse and edit a markdown wiki locally. [Obsidian](http://obsidian.md/) and [Typora](http://typora.io/) are some of those.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a "static site generator" (see a [few](https://www.staticgen.com/) [lists](https://github.com/pinceladasdaweb/Static-Site-Generators) [here](https://staticsitegenerators.net/)). Their primary function it to walk a directory and convert all the files within to HTML. You can "build" the site and then browse the files on your filesystem, or many tools also offer a "serve" command which will serve the files on localhost for previewing. For example, Github uses [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) for some parts of their service ([GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)).

However, I don't know which tools Bitbucket is using, so I can't point to anything more specific that will give you nearly identical behavior to Bitbucket's Wiki. I believe they are a Python shop (GitHub is Ruby--thus a Ruby tool), but there are multiple Python implementations of Markdown parsers so that doesn't get you all the way there.

Additionally, some static site generators are blog tools (generate posts in an ordered list by date) and others are not (generate static pages, usually as documentation). If you are looking to replicate a Wiki, you probably want a documentation generator.

I've had personal experience with Pelican (a blog engine) and MkDocs (a documentation generator), but don't know if either will fit your needs well (they both appear in the lists linked to above). Besides, this answer is getting dangerously close to an opinion/software recomendation, so I'll stop here.